# write() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

My program produces the desired results correctly as I print them on the screen using the `print()` function:

```
for k in main_dic.keys():
    s = 0
    print ('stem:', k)
    print ('word forms and frequencies:')
    for w in main_dic[k]:
        print ('%-10s ==> %10d' % (w,word_forms[w]))
        s += word_forms[w]
    print ('stem total frequency:', s)

    print ('------------------------------')
```

I want to write the results with the exact format to a text file though. I tried with this:

```
file = codecs.open('result.txt','a','utf-8')
for k in main_dic.keys():
    file.write('stem:', k)
    file.write('\n')
    file.write('word forms and frequencies:\n')
    for w in main_dic[k]:
        file.write('%-10s ==> %10d' % (w,word_forms[w]))
        file.write('\n')
        s += word_forms[w]
    file.write('stem total frequency:', s)
    file.write('\n')
    file.write('------------------------------\n')
file.close()
```

but I get the error:

> TypeError: write() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print()` takes separate arguments, `file.write()` *does not*. You can reuse `print()` to 
write to your file instead:

```
with open('result.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outf:
    for k in main_dic:
        s = 0
        print('stem:', k, file=outf)
        print('word forms and frequencies:', file=outf)
        for w in main_dic[k]:
            print('%-10s ==> %10d' % (w,word_forms[w]), file=outf)
            s += word_forms[w]
        print ('stem total frequency:', s, file=outf)
        print ('------------------------------')
```

I also used the built-in `open()`, there is no need to use the older and far less versatile `codecs.open()` in Python 3. You don't need to call `.keys()` either, looping over the dictionary directly also works.

Answer (score 2):

`file.write` is given multiple arguments when its expecting only one string argument

```
file.write('stem total frequency:', s)
                                  ^
```

The error gets raised as `'stem total frequency:', s` are treated as two different arguments. This can be fixed by concatenation

```
file.write('stem total frequency: '+str(s))
                                  ^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file.write('stem:', k)
```

You're supplying two arguments to `write` on this line, when it only wants one. In contrast, `print` is happy to take as many arguments as you care to give it. Try:

```
file.write('stem: ' + str(k))
```